# Dictionary sorting of ArrayList of Arraylist<Integer> in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort the `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<Integer>`, which looks like.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allres = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
Collections.sort(allres, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a.get(i) == b.get(i)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
});
```

But for some input, it is not giving the result of dictionary sort.

Comment: Yeah but, what's a dictionary sort? And what's the wanted output?

Comment: the `compare` method never returns `0`. what if all items are equal?

Comment: what type of output you want

Comment: The comparator is kinda weird. It compares two lists of integers by first found difference (ie list [1,6,2,3,8] would be smaller than [1,6,3,0,1]) because the the first difference is at index 2 and number 2 is smaller than 3 the rest is ignored. I don't know what is the meaning of such a comparison. There's possible IndexOutOfBoundsException if the first list is longer than the second and the items are equal. Another weird behaviour: the comparator consider first list "smaller" (returns -1) than the second in case they are the same...

Comment: @bambula This kind of comparators makes sense for version numbers and several other things. The concept is sound, it's just the implementation that's broken.

Comment: And what is "some input". Don't make us guess, provide us with details instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparator functions that contain `1` or `-1` are error prone.

Instead, you should write it like this:

```
public static int lexicographically(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    for (int i = 0, end = Math.min(a.size(), b.size()); i < end; i++) {
        int res = Integer.compare(a.get(i), b.get(i));
        if (res != 0)
            return res;
    }
    return Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size());
}
```

This style of writing comparator functions prevents various common mistakes, such as never returning 0.

The most important pattern in this style is:

1. Compare by the first criterion.
2. If the given values differ, return the comparison result and be done.
3. Take the next criterion, continue with step 1.
4. If there are no criteria left, return 0.